# How to filter rows using tidyverse in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, select, filter, tidyverse

Thought it would be an easy task but is giving me quite a headache. I am trying to `filter` rows when a particular `conditio`n is met, however, i am getting an error. Below is a sample code

```
library(tidyverse)

DF = data.frame(id = sample.int(20,20, replace = TRUE), A = runif(20, 100, 150), Dat = runif(20, 400,700))
DF_1 = DF %>% filter(id == c(6,8,17))
```

But the code give me below warning with a `DF_1` `data.frame` that has only data when `id` is equal to 8 and 17 while it should be giving me a `data.frame` for `id` being equal to 6,8, and 17.

> Warning message:
>
> > In id == c(6, 8, 17) :
> >       longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should filter using `%in%` instead of `==`.

```
DF_1 = DF %>% 
  filter(id %in% c(6,8,17))
```